# how to delete multiple files (codeigniter), according to a specific id?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hello there i am currently trying to `unlink()` multiple files from folder with specific category id, getting the right files (names) is no problem und how to unlink a file i know too, but i have a hard time to loop over the result array from the query and then delete not all files but those files out of the query, here is my code:

```
/**
 * delete category by id
 * @param $id category_id
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function delete_images($id){

    $this->db->select('post_image');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('category_id' => $id));
    $images = $query->result_array();

    if (!empty($images)){
      if(!in_array('default_image', $images)){
        foreach ($images as $image) { 
            unlink(FCPATH . 'assets/images/posts/' . $image);
        }
      }
    } else {
      $this->db->query("DELETE FROM categories WHERE categories.id = $id");
    }
}
```

Help is appreaciated, thanks.

The actual result is:

```
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: models/Category_model.php
Line Number: 71
```

Comment: unlink(FCPATH . 'assets/images/posts/' . $image['post_image']);

Comment: what is your line number with 71 here

Comment: sorry @RejoanulAlam it's the line where unlink is....

Comment: @M.Hemant that looks promising i will try it thanks

Comment: If @M.Hemant code not worked then try without `FCPATH`, more details given in answer

Comment: can you explain this line [ if(!in_array('default_image', $images)){ ] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should like

```
unlink('assets/images/posts/' . $image['post_image']);
```

You missed the index & its become an array but string was expected there

Answer (score 0):

This code Work

```
 unlink(FCPATH . 'assets/images/posts/' . $imageName);
```